# Mc gets kicked from the village because he gets ability to attract monsters which was actually a legendary ability to tame monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga

Mc gets a ability to attract monsters. He gets kicked from his village because he poses a threat to the village. Mc is sent to nearby forest where he meets his harem

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This is very terse at the moment, are there any other details you could [edit] in? This [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and the similar [Anime/Mange checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) can help if you need some pointers on what to include

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Sekai Saikyou no Shinjuu Tsukai](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/sekai-saikyou-no-shinjuu-tsukai)*.

> Mag was gifted the skill [Decoy], **a skill capable of attracting monsters and causing disasters**. As such, he was banished from the city. Therefore, he decided to live alone in a hunting cabin deep in the mountains. However, there, he draws the attention of Divine Beasts: Loa the Dragon (a beautiful girl), Fiana the Phoenix (another beautiful girl), and Kelpie the Maera (another beautiful girl). In the end, Mag decides to spend a easygoing life in the mountains with the Divine Beasts. But the skill [Decoy] is not making it easy for him...

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question. The main character receives a skill that attracts monsters, and is promptly kicked out of the town. While living alone, his skill attracts numerous beautiful women that happen to be monsters.

[image: Kicked out]

Comment: ^_^ You have the page capture. I will yield to you. It can be found with a Google search for `manga ability "attract monsters" taming`